Error polyfilling timers-browserify in Angular 18
I have recently created a new project in Angular 18 that requires xml2js. In local development everything works fine, but for production build problems started with node timers lib.
The xml2js needs setImmediate = require('timers').setImmediate; from timers lib. But is not available when building because is a node feature not from browser and I got the next error
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "timers"
I tried to install timers-browserify add to tsconfig.json and angular.json
"paths": {
    "timers": ["./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js"]
}

"scripts": ["./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js"]

But it is still failing.
How can I configure my project to use the new build and to use de browser pollyfill?
Thank you

This library is not compatible with the browser runtime, you should look for another one.
